# Changing the tooltip in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplotly

I am trying to alter the tooltip in ggplotly. At the moment the tooltip is showing `Data1` and `reorder(Data2, Data1)`. I wish this to show `Data2` and `Data1`. My approach is below.

```
   gg <- ggplot(df)+
        geom_point(aes(x = Data1, y = reorder(Data2, Data1))) +
    
    ggplotly(gg,tooltip = c("Data2", "Data1"))
```

I feel I've followed the official documentation: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.3/topics/ggplotly
I've also followed the various methods available here:
https://plotly-r.com/controlling-tooltips.html

Yet this does not seem to change anything. Any direction is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df <- cars
names(df) <- c("Data1", "Data2")
yy <- names(df)[2]
###  define what you want to display in tooltip
text <- paste("Data2:",df$Data2, "\nData1:", df$Data1)

gg <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = Data1, y = reorder(Data2, Data1), text=text)) + labs(y=yy)
  
  ggplotly(gg,tooltip = c("text"))
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still no luck unfortunately,

Comment: @CiaranOBrien, please try the updated code.

Comment: this seems to work well with your reproducible example. I'll backwards engineer it to my actual data. Thank you again. It's highly appreciated.